# How to specify that a python object must be two types at once

Tags: python, typing

I'm using the Python typing module throughout my project, and I was wondering if there was a way to specify that a given object must be of two different types, at once. This most obviously arises when you have specified two protocols, and expect a single object to fulfil both:

```
class ReturnsNumbers(Protocol):
    def get_number(self) -> Int:
        pass

class ReturnsLetters(Protocol):
    def get_letter(self) -> str:
        pass

def get_number_and_letter(x: <what should this be?>) -> None:
    print(x.get_number(), x.get_letter())
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a new type that inherits from [all types you wish to combine, as well as `Protocol`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#merging-and-extending-protocols).

```
class ReturnsNumbersAndLetters(ReturnsNumbers, ReturnsLetters, Protocol):
    pass

def get_number_and_letter(x: ReturnsNumbersAndLetters) -> None:
    print(x.get_number(), x.get_letter())
```

Comment: @Amadan Fixed, and added a link to the relevant PEP. I had assumed that since the base classes already inherited from `Protocol` this was not necessary to do again, but `Protocol` is special.

Comment: Thanks - this seems like the best way to go.

Comment: Damn, I kinda wish there was sugar for this, like `def get_number_and_letter(x: ReturnsNumbers + ReturnsLetters)` or `def get_number_and_letter(x: Sum[ReturnsNumbers, ReturnsLetters])`. Maybe `&` instead of `+` to complement `Union`'s `|`, and `And` instead of `Sum`.

Comment: What if you want to specify a concrete class that also satisfies a protocol? This gives a “protocol class cannot derive from non-protocol class” error.

Answer (score 6):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213#issuecomment-473155653) on the relevant issue, you can make a simple intersection protocol:

```
class ReturnsNumbersAndLetters(ReturnsNumbers, ReturnsLetters, Protocol):
    pass
```

then use it instead:

```
def get_number_and_letter(x: ReturnsNumbersAndLetters) -> None:
    print(x.get_number(), x.get_letter())
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the other solutions presented have merit except you may have to deal with the case where you have two separate objects that both implement both classes. If you know for sure that the object you want inherits from both `ReturnsNumbers` and `ReturnsLetters`, you could do this:

```
T = TypeVar(bound = ReturnsNumbers|ReturnsLetters)

def get_number_and_letter(x: T) -> None:
    print(x.get_number(), x.get_letter())
```

This avoids the explicit definition of a (possibly) useless class while ensuring that you get the type-hinting that you want.

You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar).

Comment: Thanks - that is tidy way to do it, but in this case I don't anticipate that the object will be inheriting from those classes - the intention is just to ensure that they implement the methods.

Comment: In that case, you should create two base classes with those methods on them and then make sure anything that uses them inherits the base classes. AFAIK there's no way to do interfacing in Python so this is probably the closest you'll get.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The syntax `TypeVar("name", type1, type2)` is for setting constraints, i.e. the type must be either `type1` or `type2` (and not its subtypes). To allow subtypes you need to set a bound (`TypeVar("name", bound=base_type)`), but there's no syntax to express an intersection type other than the protocol solution given in other answers.

Comment: @ZecongHu You are correct, I think. The Python documentation was not clear about what this did but it implied that it was a type intersection. On second examination, this wasn't the case. However, it appears that `Union` does offer this functionality.